# python random lottery number generator game

Tags: python-3.x, random, code-generation, google-colaboratory

I have to make a game where like the lottery my program generates 5 random numbers from a list of numbers 1-50 and one additional number from a list of numbers 1-20 and combines them into a final list that reads eg: (20, 26, 49, 01, 11, + 06) where two numbers are never repeated like (22, 11, 34, 44, 01, + 22) <--- this is what I don't want

attached below is the code I have written yet how do I make it so two numbers or more are never repeated and to add the + into my list without the "" signs

input:
    import random

```
a = list(range(1,51))
b = random.randint(1, 20)

temp = []

for i in range(5):
  random.shuffle(a) 
  temp.append(random.choice(a[:5])) 
temp.append('+')
temp.append(b)

print(temp)
```

output:

```
[14, 12, 3, 16, 23, '+', 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not add `+` without the `'` around them - they mark the + as string.

Also: you shuffle your list - simply take the first 5 values - they are random and your list does not contain any dupes so you are golden:

```
nums = list(range(1,51))
random.shuffle(nums)
five_nums = nums[:5]
print(five_nums)     # [44, 23, 34, 38, 3]
```

To simplyfy it, use:

```
import random

# creates 5 unique elements from 1..50 and adds a + and a [0-19]+1 number
randlist = random.sample(range(1,51),k=5) + ["+", random.choice(range(20))+1]
print(randlist)
```

Now you got mixed numbers and strings - you can create a combined string by:

```
print("You drew {} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(*randlist))
```

To create a string like

```
[48, 2, 9, 6, 41, '+', 8]

You drew 48 2 9 6 41 + 8
```

---

Doku:

- [random.sample (draw without putting back)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import random
randList, run = [], 0
while run < 6:
   number = random.randint(1,51)
   if number not in randList:
        if run == 5:
            randList.append('+'+str(number))
            break
        randList.append(number)
        run += 1
print(randList)
```

You can't have a string in a list without quotes, however, if you were to print every item in the list (using a for loop or join), the quotes wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate a list of 7 random numbers

```
import random

def main():

    numbers = []

    for num in range(7):

        num = random.randrange(50)

        numbers.append(num)

    print(numbers)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

#No repeating numbers and sorted output

```
import random
picks =  int (input("How Many Picks ?: "))

for i in range (picks):
    num_list = random.sample(range(1, 45), 5,)
    num_list.sort()
    joker_num = random.sample(range(1, 20), 1)
    print("Lucky Numbers :", num_list, "-", "Joker :", joker_num)
```

Answer (score -1):

It didn't work because you need to have

```
import random
```

Comment: OP wrote `import random` right after `input:` in case you didn't see it