# I am trying to create a code to simulate a lottery game. I need to check if one of the generated numbers already has been generated before

Tags: python

I already have a working code but I noticed that sometimes 2 or more of the same numbers would be generated in a list and therefore mess up the whole game. I am not very experienced in python so I have no clue on how to check if the number has been used on the list and if so, on how to generate a new, unused one!

I need a new piece of code to check for this problem and if it happens, to regenerate the number.
Here is my existing code:

```python
import random

luckynumber = []
inputnumber = []

correct_numbers = 0

print('Welcome to the game!')
print('Please insert 6 numbers from 1 to 49:')

for number in range(0, 6):
  randomnumber = random.randint(1, 49)
  luckynumber.append(randomnumber)

for number in range(0, 6):
  player_number = int(input())
  inputnumber.append(player_number)

for correctnumber in luckynumber:
  for player_number in inputnumber:
    if player_number == correctnumber:
      correct_numbers = correct_numbers + 1

print(f'You gessed {correct_numbers} correct numbers!')
print(f'Original correct numbers: {luckynumber}')
```

Comment: `random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)` will give you 6 random numbers from 1-49 that are guaranteed to be different - so you could do that and not have to worry about checking for duplicates. Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: @slothrop - you should put this into *Answer* to be acknowledged, not in *comments*...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python random lottery number generator game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846420/python-random-lottery-number-generator-game)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.sample` will give you a sample of *k* random elements from a population, with each element guaranteed to be different. So you can do that and not have to worry about finding and replacing duplicates.

[Link to standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

In your code you'd do:

```
luckynumber = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)
```

Note that `randint(1, 49)` gives you numbers between 1 and 49 inclusive, but `range` gives a range of numbers that *ex*cludes that last element. So here we have `range(1, 50)` to select from the numbers 1-49 inclusive.

Comment: This seems like a really good solution, I just wonder where I would use this, or rather what I would substitute and write this instead?

Comment: You could eliminate the `for` loop that populates `luckynumber` in your current code, and replace it with this line

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), as pointed out by @slothrop:

```py
luckynumber = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I need to check if one of the generated numbers already has been generated before*

Then you do just do that, `if randomnumber not in luckynumber:`

```
import random

luckynumber = []
while len(luckynumber) < 6:
  randomnumber = random.randint(1, 49)
  if randomnumber not in luckynumber:
    luckynumber.append(randomnumber)

print(luckynumber)
```